# Why does "header.get() + footer.get()" result in deadlock, when using a single threaded Executor?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is listing 8.1 in [Java Concurrency In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601):

```
public class ThreadDeadlock  {
   ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

   public class RenderPageTask implements Callable<String>  {
      public String call() throws Exception  {
         Future<String> header, footer;
         header = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("header.html"));
         footer = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("footer.html"));
         String page = renderBody();

         //Will deadlock -- task waiting for result of subtask
         return header.get() + page + footer.get();
      }
   }
}
```

It's in

Chapter 8: **Thread Pools** > Section 8.1.1 **Thread starvation deadlock**

and has the caption:

> "Task that deadlocks in a single-threaded `Executor`. *Don't do this.*"

Why does this result in a deadlock? I *thought* `header.get()` is called, and then `footer.get()` is called, which each result appended to the string. Why wouldn't a single threaded Executor be enough to run these one after the other?

Relevant chapter text:

> 8.1.1 Thread starvation deadlock
>
> If tasks that depend on other tasks execute in a thread pool, they can deadlock. In a single-threaded executor, a task that submits another task to the same executor and waits for its result will always deadlock. The second task sits on the work queue until the first task completes, but the first will not complete because it is waiting for the resut of the second task. The same thing can happen in larger thread pools if all threads are executing tasks that are blocked waiting for other tasks still on the work queue. This is called *thread starvation deadlock*, and can occur whenever a pool task initiates an unbounded blocking wait for some resource or condition that can succeed only through the action of another pool task, such as waiting for the return value or side effect of another task, unless you can guarantee that the pool is large enough.
>
> `ThreadDeadlock` in Listing 8.1 illustrates thread starvation deadldock. `RenderPageTask` submits two additional tasks to the `Executor` o fetch the page header and footer, renders the page body, waits for the results of the header and footer tasks, and then combines the header, body, and footer into the finished page. With a single-threaded executor, `ThreadDeadlock` will always deadlock. Similarly, tasks coordinating amongst themselves with a barrier could also cause thread starvation deadlock if the pool is not big enough.

Comment: I don't see any deadlock. What does `LoadFileTask` do?

Comment: Is this book freely available? I can't seem to read the sections you're referring to without paying around 25$. Additionally, we're missing some code here, like, what is `LoadFileTask`? This makes it hard to analyze the problem or explain why it deadlocks. Though this snippet doesn't contain anything executable so there is nothing to deadlock as there is nothing to run.

Comment: Does the book say taht the RenderPageTask itself is already running inside the same executor ? That would deadlock indeed...

Comment: There's no code to show. `LoadFileTask` is a made up task. I'll add the text of the chapter...

Comment: **In a single-threaded executor, a task that submits another task to the same executor and waits for its result will always deadlock. The second task sits on the work queue until the first task completes, but the first will not complete because it is waiting for the resut of the second task.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual deadlock will occur will occur as soon as an instance of `RenderPageTask` is submitted to the very same executor instance where it submits its task.

For example, add

```
exec.submit(new RenderPageTask());
```

and you will experience a deadlock.

Of course this can be considered a problem of the surrounding code
(i.e., you could simply define and document that your `RenderPageTask` should not be submitted to this executor instance), but a good design would avoid such pitfalls entirely.

A possible solution for this would be to use [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), which uses work stealing to avoid this form of possible deadlocks.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see. The single threaded executor handles all Callables in the order they were submitted, but the first callable can't return as it depends on the second and third callable that it submits itself.

Comment: On a sidenote, this is why I prefer working with delegation much more than working with Future objects and thread blocking.

Comment: I don't see where `RenderPageTask` is submitted to the executor. The only `submit`s in the code are for the header and footer sub-tasks. I understand that if the overall "render" task was submitted to the executor, that it would deadlock in a single-threaded pool, because it is waiting on its subtasks...which need that thread to work in.

Comment: I see now. `RenderPageTask` is a Callable. In order to execute, it *has* to be submitted to the executor in some other code we're not being shown. The question this was just marked a duplicate of makes this clear.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I bet that `RenderPageTask` is submitted to the same executor pool that other tasks are, so another tasks wont start until `RenderPageTask` finishes - but this will never ocure - we have deadlock