# How do I cancel spawned Callables after a Future.cancel?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an `ExecutorService` to which I submit n `Callable`s. In each of these n `Callable`s, I spawn new `Callable`s which are submitted to the same `ExecutorService`.
When I encounter a `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` on any of the first n `Callable`s at their respective `Future.get()`, I do `Future.cancel(true)` on that `Callable`. I also need to cancel the tasks which I submitted because of these cancelled `Callable`s.

One way I could do this is to store the spawned `Callable`s in a map of lists somewhere up in the call stack, and while cancelling the `Callable`, use it to find its children and cancel them too. But this does not seem a very good solution to me, as the logic of cancellation should reside somewhere closer.

Is there a handler/a better way that could give me this flexibility?

Comment: It seems like the root `Callable` should be coordinating its spawned `Callable`s. As such, when it receives its _interrupt_ for the cancellation, it should call `cancel` on the its "children".

Comment: Watch out with having callablea that block on their own callables on the same pool. That's a recipe for deadlock.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do you mean to say that I should have a try catch block inside my root Callable to detect ThreadInterruptedException to do the cleanup? Will Future.cancel() ensure the triggering of this Exception?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My Callables are blocking on their children. The children do not block on any of their ancestors. So how can a deadlock occur? Maybe you wanted to just say this as a hygiene principle (and not exactly applicable here)?

Comment: Yeah, just in general. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101862/why-does-header-get-footer-get-result-in-deadlock-when-using-a-single-t), for example.

Comment: `Future#cancel` is usually implemented by interrupting the thread doing the work in the `ExecutorService`. You should listen for that and propagate it to the children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I encounter a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException on any of the first n Callables at their respective Future.get(), I do Future.cancel() on that Callable. I also need to cancel the tasks which I submitted because of these cancelled Callables.

When you call `future.cancel(false)` it will only stop the job from executing if it is not already running.  You wouldn't have a problem in this case because no "sub-jobs" have been created.

So I assume you are talking about `future.cancel(true)` which will interrupt the thread if the job is already running.  It is important to realize that this interruption *only* affects the few methods that throw `InterruptedException` – like `Thread.sleep(...)`, `obj.wait(...)`, etc..  Otherwise you will need to test for the interrupt flag in your code.  For example:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   ...
}
```

What I would do is to have each of your jobs just keep a list of the `Future`s "sub-jobs" that it has spawned.  When it catches an `InterruptedException` or when it notices that its thread interrupt flag has been set then it can call `future.cancel(true)` on all of the jobs it forked.

Something like:

```
final List<Future<...>> subJobs = new ArrayList<>();
...
while (true) {
   if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      cleanupSubJobs(subJobs);
      break;
   }
   try {
      Thread.sleep(...);
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      // always a good pattern
      Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
      cleanupSubJobs(subJobs);
      return;
   }
   ...
   if (weNeedSubJob) {
      subJobs.add(threadPool.submit(...));
   }
}
...
private void cleanupSubJobs(List<Future<...>> subJobs) {
   for (Future<...> subJob : subJobs) {
      subJob.cancel(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There does not seem to be an easy way to introduce an infinite while loop inside my second level Callable. It basically submits the subjobs to the thread pool and then waits for the subjobs to return. However, I see that Future.get() throws an InterruptedException. If I catch that in the second level Callable, I can cancel all my subtasks there.